How Many I/O Operations Are Required to Transfer 20 KB of Data from Disk to RAM?
I’m trying to understand how many I/O operations are needed to transfer data from disk to RAM, given specific parameters.
Consider the following scenario:

Data to Transfer: 20 KB (20,480 bytes) from disk to RAM.

Buffer Size: 4 KB (4,096 bytes) - This is the size of the buffer used for reading data from the disk.

Disk I/O: Data is read in chunks that fit into the buffer.


Questions:

Number of I/O Operations: Given a 4 KB buffer size, how many I/O operations are required to transfer all 20 KB of data from the disk to RAM?

Impact of Buffer Size: How does changing the buffer size (e.g., to 8 KB or 16 KB) affect the number of I/O operations required?

Data Bus Width Consideration: How does the data bus width (64 bits or 8 bytes) affect the efficiency of these operations, if at all? Specifically, does the data bus width impact the number of I/O operations needed, or is it more related to the speed of data transfer?

Buffer Size vs. Data Bus Width: Which factor is more influential in determining the number of I/O operations: the buffer size or the data bus width?


I am looking for a clear explanation of how buffer size and data bus width impact the number of I/O operations required and the overall efficiency of data transfer.
This should help clarify the relationship between buffer size, data bus width, and I/O operations.

What do you mean by an "I/O operation"?  Are you counting every read/write of an MMIO register by the CPU (and/or port I/O like x86's in / out instructions)?  Or group of operations in a single kernel function to submit a request for one block?  If so, does your disk controller use DMA or does the CPU have to copy every byte or word itself?  (In x86 PC history, this is called programmed-IO aka PIO).  Are you counting PCI messages?  Or counting bus cycles taken up by DMA, if that's used?  Is there just one "data bus" shared between memory and I/O, like in 8086 IBM-PCs?

@PeterCordes consider the above scenario you are opening a 20kb file . The file store in need to be loaded in ram. so here the data need to transferred. Reading the file from disk requires how many read operation and writing the file in ram requires how many write operation. In programming generally a buffer is used to store the moving data for better I/O performance.but data bus width determines the amount of data can be transferred in single go . So my confusion is saying the buffer is 1024 bytes. It reads 1024 bytes and 1024 bytes or it reads 8-bytes and write 8-bytes because of data-bus.

@PeterCordes was it read every 8-bytes from 1024 bytes readed from the disk and then write every 8-bytes to the ram?

@PeterCordes exactly i need the entire process. How does data is readed from the disk using buffer and data bus and how does it write to the ram using buffer and data bus and vice versa.

Modern processors use DMA, which bypasses the processor data bus, transferring data directly from the (disk) device to memory.  An operating system may load data from a device (via DMA) into an operating system buffer and copy it later to user memory (using processor data bus), or it may load the data directly into user memory.  The user program may also buffer the data within its own user memory.  When the user program reads memory then that same data traverses the processor data bus.  So, you'll need some context to answer your questions: is DMA being used, what operating system, etc..

Opening a file in and of itself is a complex operation involving reading the file system directories to locate the data bytes for the file.  So, reading a file  is one thing, but opening the file is another.  You need to know the file system and operating system.

The number of MMIO reads/writes (or PCIe transactions) necessary to set up a DMA transfer depends on the design of the disk controller.  e.g. https://wiki.osdev.org/AHCI#Example_-_Read_hard_disk_sectors shows some code to set up a SATA command for an AHCI controller, assuming it's already detected and initialized.  That toy example spin-waits for completion; a real OS would have the device raise an interrupt when the transfer completed.  It starts with port->is = -1; which is one MMIO access (port is a pointer to volatile struct, the MMIO address), and there's more...

A different I/O device would have different ways of setting up commands that might take more or fewer MMIO operations to set up a read or write of a sector.  So you need to specify in more detail what you're counting, and depending on that, you might need more detail about the system you're uing.

In programming generally a buffer is used to store the moving data for better I/O performance - For reading a file from disk, the destination "buffer" in a normal OS is a page of memory from the pagecache which will hold this file's data until we need to free up space.  You wouldn't have a dedicate read buffer that you read into and then copy from RAM to RAM, except for the copy done by a read system call from the appropriate page of the kernel's pagecache to a userspace process's memory.

If your I/O device can only DMA into contiguous blocks of memory (physical address space, or optionally virtual if you have an IOMMU), then you couldn't set up one big request if you needed the results in scattered pages.  So normally you would want to allocate enough space for a bigger multi-sector read to reduce the command overhead for the same number of bytes transferred.
